# Fix the width of pen when changing resolution of image

Tags: c#, graphics, resolution, pen

I can draw a line on image by using below code. Width of pen is fixed as 5. There is a dropdown for selecting resolution of screen (640*480,352*288,320*240 etc). When selecting it, screen will  change into that resolution. As a result the width of pen seems different. In each resolution pen width looks different. How can I fix the width of pen for all resolution?

```
  public void DrawLineInt(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

    int x1 = 100;
    int y1 = 100;
    int x2 = 500;
    int y2 = 100;
    // Draw line to screen.
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine the width of the pen remains the same, but appears bigger because the screen is smaller or bigger. Create a method that will scale your pen width in the same ratio as your screen resolution.

Comment: yes it appears bigger. you mean penwidth= (screen width/height)*1/100 ?

Comment: What is the *resolution of screen*? Do you mean the size of the Bitmap?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Ideally some code that uses the same size pen for two images so that we can see what the difference you're describing is.

Comment: @jimi actually it is a video.   videoSource1.VideoResolution =
                                 videoSource1.VideoCapabilities[comboBox1Resolution.SelectedIndex];

Comment: You could scale the Pen on the scale factor defined by a reference measure. E.g., if the reference measure is `640x480`, then the Pen at `320x240` could be `int p1 = (int)(p * ((float)320 / 640)) + 1;`. Which will give you `3`. So, if you scale to `1280x1024`, the Pen would be `11`. It's better to have odd Pen sizes (because of the way the Pen is used, half inside and half outside the bounding rectangle).

Comment: But you could also. probably better, use floating point values for the Pen.